# Tinymce: Toolbar location at bottom of Editor

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-4

I am using TinyMCE 4 with modern theme. I want to set the location of toolbar at the bottom of editor (just like where the status bar is)

Here is the code, but its not working:

```
tinymce.init({
                selector: 'textarea#editor',
                menubar: false,
                statusbar: false,
                resize: false,
                height: textEditHeight,
                theme_modern_toolbar_location : "bottom",
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

based on the tinyMCE documentation, you can only use 
theme_modern_toolbar_location : "bottom"

when you use Advanced theme.

```
theme : "advanced",
```

Full example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// O2k7 skin
tinyMCE.init({
        // General options
        mode : "exact",
        elements : "elm1",
        theme : "advanced",
        skin : "o2k7",
        plugins : "spellchecker,pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template,imagemanager,filemanager",

        // Theme options
        theme_advanced_buttons1 : "save,newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
        theme_advanced_buttons2 : "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
        theme_advanced_buttons3 : "tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions,iespell,media,advhr,|,print,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen",
        theme_advanced_buttons4 : "insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute,|,styleprops,spellchecker,|,cite,abbr,acronym,del,ins,attribs,|,visualchars,nonbreaking,template,blockquote,pagebreak,|,insertfile,insertimage",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
        theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
        theme_advanced_resizing : true,
        theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "bottom"
});

</script>

<form method="post" action="dump.php">
        <textarea id="elm1" name="elm1" style="width:100%">
        </textarea>


</form>
```

Comment: But the advanced theme is removed from TinyMCE 4. So, that means, I cannot use theme_modern_toolbar_location : "bottom",

Comment: as in the documentation, this property can only be used with legacy version 3.x. i don't see any control of the toolbar location in the new 4.x

Comment: Sorry to revive a very old post, but is there any changes since 2013 on this issue? I really want my TinyMCE toolbar to be at the bottom of the text box.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old post, but I figured I would share my solution.

I add an event handler for the 'init' event and then use jQuery to change the order of the toolbar and editor divs.

```
tinyMCE.init({
...

    setup: function (ed) {
      ed.on('init', function (evt) {
          var toolbar = $(evt.target.editorContainer)
                            .find('>.mce-container-body >.mce-toolbar-grp');
          var editor = $(evt.target.editorContainer)
                            .find('>.mce-container-body >.mce-edit-area');

          // switch the order of the elements
          toolbar.detach().insertAfter(editor);
      });
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I have figured out a way , with pure CSS . Just add this code in your custom css file or in style tag in html .

```
#mceu_5-body{
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
```

**What it does is reverse the direction in which the divs are arranged i.e. from bottom to top**. The only downside is that flex is a modern CSS property, thus not supported in old browsers

Comment: I had to use `.tox div.tox-editor-container` as the selector instead because I'm using an Angular wrapper, but this worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

On one of their blog post they say that they have removed advanced_theme. So, if we want to use toolbar at the bottom of TinyMCE, we will have to create a new skin.

Answer (score 0):

Insert below css code bottom of your custom css file

```
.mce-top-part{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0
}
```